# No encuentro el error que produce este Heredoc (PHP)

Tags: php

El código es este:

```
<div class="panel-body">
<?php
$login_form = <<<EOD
  <form role="form" name="login" id="login" method="POST" action="check_login.php">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Usuario:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Contraseña:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
      </div>                                    
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Ingresar</button>
  </form>
  EOD;
$msg = $_GET['msg'];  //GET the message
if($msg!='') echo '<p>'.$msg.'</p>'; //If message is set echo it
echo "<h1>Please enter your Login Information</h1>";
echo $login_form;
?>
</div>
```

El error que me devuelve es:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (`T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE`), expecting identifier (`T_STRING`) or variable (`T_VARIABLE`) or number (`T_NUM_STRING`) on line 91

La línea 91 es:

```
$msg = $_GET['msg'];  //GET the message
```

Estuve leyendo que el `EOD;` final no tiene que tener espacios y no lo tiene.

Comment: Formatea bien el código porque, con los heredoc, el formateo es clave para entender qué pasa...

Comment: Hola @Carlos , ¿se solucionó tu problema con las respuestas que te dimos?

Answer (score 1):

El problema radica en que el `EOD` o cualquier cadena que uses como delimitador [debe ocupar la línea completa excluyendo el `;`](http://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> **Advertencia**:
>
> Es muy importante señalar que la línea con el
>   identificador de cierre no debe contener ningún otro carácter, excepto
>   un punto y coma (;). Esto, en especial, significa que **el identificador no debe estar sangrado**, y que no debe existir ningún espacio ni
>   tabulación antes o después del punto y coma.

No te dejes confundir por el hecho de que el problema lo esté dando la línea inmediatamente posterior al problema real.

Así que aunque tengas sangrado el código PHP, debe comenzar al inicio de la línea la cadena delimitadora:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <?php                       
    $login_form = <<<EOD        
    <form role="form" name="login" id="login" method="POST" action="check_login.php">
        <div class="form-group">    
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Usuario:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username">
        </div>                      
        <div class="form-group">    
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Contraseña:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
        </div>                      
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Ingresar</button> 
    </form>                     
EOD;
/* ^^ debe comenzar al inicio de la línea, sin sangrado */
    $msg = $_GET['msg'];  //GET the message
    if($msg!='') echo '<p>'.$msg.'</p>'; //If message is set echo it 
    echo "<h1>Please enter your Login Information</h1>";
    echo $login_form;           
    ?>                          
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es muy posible que lo que te esté pasando es que el token `EOD` final no está pegado a la izquierda (sin espacios), lo cual es un requerimiento de los *heredoc* como bien comentas.